# PHP how to fix Illegal offset type error?

Tags: php

So I have this $_POST which I am trying to check if it is set but when I do that, it gives me the error in the title.

The $_POST contains array within array.  So that could be the reason.  $_POST has value if the checkbox is checked otherwise nothing is posted.

So example of what $_POST would contain:

```
array() => 'item-one' => array( 102 ) => 'on'
```

I am using this in PHP:

```
function testing( $db_id ) {
    $fields = array( 'one', 'two' );

    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
         if ( isset( $_POST['item-' . $field][$db_id] ) ) {
              // do something
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Please show what vars are in `$_POST`.

Comment: Is `$db_id` defined anywhere?

Comment: I updated it...hopefully it is more clear...

Comment: @code-jaff - it does...it is passed in as an argument..

Comment: Nope, it's not clear. It's not clear what are the keys and what are the values in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
     if (isset($_POST['item-'.$field]) and in_array($db_id,$_POST['item-'.$field])){
          // do something
     }
}
```

**Alternatively** you can try it like,

```
$fields=array('item-one','item-two')
foreach( $fields as $key=>$field ) {
     if (isset($_POST[$field]) and in_array($db_id,$_POST[$field])){
          // do something
     }
}
```

Comment: I think Rhonan showed the correct solution but did not exactly state why. In the sample given in the question, there is a need to check every $_POST element, so first check if $_POST['item-one'] exists, and IF, THEN check if also $_POST['item-one']['102'] exists

Comment: @Kaffee - thanks for the info however I thought isset function would know that...

Answer (score 0):

Try with [in_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php):

```
$fields = array( 'one', 'two' );

foreach( $fields as $field ) {
     if ( in_array($_POST['item-' . $field][$db_id], $fields) ) {
          // do something
     }
}
```